# Set syntax batch script error

Tags: batch-file, set, syntax-error

I would like to define a variable but my syntax might not be appropriate. In this example I need scovar to be equal to what is inside the quotation marks.

```
set scovar="(ct_scope_code.name = 'CO' AND ct_variant.name = 'CO') OR (ct_scope_code.name = 'BU' AND ct_variant.name = 'CO')"
```

The thing is when I use these quotation marks, scovar is equal to the whole sentence including the quotation marks. And when I do not use quotation marks, the script does not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Move the opening quote before the variable name:

```
set "scovar=(ct_scope_code.name = 'CO' AND ct_variant.name = 'CO') OR (ct_scope_code.name = 'BU' AND ct_variant.name = 'CO')"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If whatever==somethingelse (
set ct_scope_code.name=CO 
set ct_variant.name=CO 
) else (
set ct_scope_code.name=BU 
set ct_variant.name=CO
)
```

Could be what you want. You are making **the syntax up**, so as you are only person that understands it, so it's hard to tell what you mean.

See `set /?` and `if /?` for help.

Or maybe this

```
If Somevar==somevar (
set "scovar=ct_scope_code.name = 'CO' AND ct_variant.name = 'CO'" 
) else (
set "scovar=ct_scope_code.name = 'BU' AND ct_variant.name = 'CO'"
)
set s
pause
```